# Composition of piecewise functions?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, function-and-relation-composition

Let
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
2x &\text{, x > 3}\\
x^2 &\text{, x $\leq$ 3}
\end{cases}$$
and
$$g(x)=
\begin{cases}
x &\text{, x > 2}\\
5 &\text{, x $<$ 2}
\end{cases}$$

I'm asked to find $f(g(x))$, but I don't know how to do it. I handled combinations before, but never of piecewise functions and I don't know where to begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x>2$, then $g(x)=x>2$. Hence, 
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(g(x))=f(x)=
\begin{cases}
2x&\text{ if }x>3\\
x^{2}&\text{ if }2<x\leq 3
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}.
$$
If $x<2$, then  $g(x)=5>3$.  Hence,
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(g(x))=f(5)=2\cdot 5=10.
\end{aligned}
$$

In conclusion, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(g(x))=
\begin{cases}
2x&\text{ if }x>3\\
x^{2}&\text{ if }2<x\leq 3\\
10&\text{ if }x<2
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}.
$$

Comment: Hello @ervx can you take a look to this similar question please? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4365986/composition-of-piecewise-functions-strange-result