# Composition of piecewise functions - Strange result

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, solution-verification, function-and-relation-composition

I'm trying to get $f(g(x))$, where:

$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{1-x} &\text{if } x \leq 1 \\
x &\text{if } x > 1
\end{cases}
$$

$$
g(x)=
\begin{cases}
x + 1 &\text{if } x \geq 0 \\
x^2 &\text{if } x < 0
\end{cases}
$$

I
followed [these steps](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2059960/composition-of-piecewise-functions):

1. $g(x \geq 0) = x + 1$ hence:
   $$
   f(g(x \geq 0)) = 
   \begin{cases}
   \sqrt{1 - (x + 1)} = \sqrt{-x}  &\text{if } 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\
   x + 1 &\text{if } x > 1
   \end{cases}
   $$

**but $\sqrt{-x}$ is not real!** Is it correct? if not, what is the right result?

2. $g(x < 0) = x^2$ hence:

$$
f(g(x < 0)) = \sqrt{1 - x^2} \quad \text{if } x < 0
$$

---

EDIT: steps to get the @JoséCarlosSantos solution

$
\boldsymbol{g(x) \leq 1}
$

$$
\begin{cases}
x + 1 \leq 1 \\
x^2 \leq 1
\end{cases}
$$

$$
\begin{cases}
x \leq 0 \\
-1 \leq x \leq 1
\end{cases}
$$

so $-1 \leq x \leq 0$.

$
\boldsymbol{g(x) > 1}
$

$$
\begin{cases}
x + 1 > 1 \\
x^2 > 1
\end{cases}
$$

$$
\begin{cases}
x > 0 \\
x < - 1 \text{ or } x > 1
\end{cases}
$$

this means that I can split it in two subsystems:

1. $$ \begin{cases} x > 0 \\ x < - 1 \end{cases} $$ this system does not have any solution;
2. $$
   \begin{cases}
   x > 0 \\
   x > 1
   \end{cases}
   $$ the solution is $x > 1$.

Putting together the results of the two subsystems: $x > 1$. I made a mistake, the right result should be $x < - 1$ or $x > 0$.

Comment: Consider a particular value to see where you went wrong.  $f(g(0.5)) = f(0.5+1) = f(1.5) = 1.5$.  Consider, for $x> 0$ one has that $g(x)=x+1>1$ so we would have when applying $f(g(x))$ to an $x>0$ we would initially have it falling under $g$'s first case which would cause it to be falling under $f$'s second case.  Consider separately $-1\leq x<0$ and $x=0$ as well as another case for $x<-1$

Comment: You will have $f(g(x))=\begin{cases}x+1&\text{if }x>0\\?&\text{if }x=0\\?&\text{if }-1\leq x<0\\?&\text{if }x<-1\end{cases}$, leaving you to fill in the remaining $?$'s.  To emphasize, to decide whether to use the first case of $f$ or the second case, it doesn't matter the value of the input to $f\circ g$ as much as it matters the value of what is the *input of $f$* which is no longer simply $x$ but rather has since been modified by $g$ to become $g(x)$.

Comment: Hello @JMoravitz thank you for your comments, maybe I found the answer (can I merge the last two?):
$f(g(x))=\begin{cases} x+1&\text{if }x>0\\ 1&\text{if }x=0\\ x^2&\text{if }-1\leq x<0\\ x^2&\text{if }x<-1\end{cases}$

Comment: Check again.  $f(g(0))$ is what?  If we apply $g$ to zero we get a result of ____ and if we plug *that* into $f$?  Then, how about the case of $-1\leq x<0$.  When $g$ is applied to such an input how large is the result?  What case would it have fallen under when we apply $f$ to that result?

Comment: In the part that you have added to the question, you wrote $g(x)\leqslant1$ and then$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}x+1\leqslant1\\x^2\leqslant1,\end{array}\right.$$without saying what has the first thing to do with the second one. If you meant to say that they are equivalent, you are wrong. The assertion $g(x)\leqslant1$ is equivalent to$$\begin{cases}x+1\leqslant1&\text{ if }x\geqslant0\\x^2\leqslant1&\text{ if }x<0,\end{cases}$$which is not the same thing.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thank you for your precious clarification. Can you tell me the next step? I mean, which intervals should I compare so substitute the right pieces of g inside f?

Comment: If $x\geqslant0$, then $x+1\leqslant1\iff x=0$. And, if $x<0$, $x^2\leqslant1\iff x\in[-1,0)$. So,$$f\bigl(g(x)\bigr)=\begin{cases}\sqrt{1-(x+1)}=\sqrt x&\text{ if }x=0\\\sqrt{1-x^2}&\text{ if }x\in[-1,0).\end{cases}$$And now you will still have to see what happens when $g(x)>1$.

Comment: Perfect @JoséCarlosSantos The last step regarding $g(x)>1$ is:

$$ f\bigl(g(x) > 1\bigr)=
\begin{cases}
x + 1 &\text{ if } x > 0  \\
x^2 &\text{ if } x < 1
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since$$g(x)=\begin{cases}x+1&\text{ if }x\geqslant0\\x^2&\text{ if }x<0,\end{cases}$$you have$$g(x)\leqslant1\text{ if }x\in[-1,0]\quad\text{and}\quad g(x)>1\text{ if }x<-1\text{ or }x>0.$$So,\begin{align}f\bigl(g(x)\bigr)&=\begin{cases}\sqrt{1-g(x)}&\text{ if }x\in[-1,0]\\g(x)&\text{ if }x<-1\text{ or }x>0\end{cases}\\&=\begin{cases}\sqrt{1-x^2}&\text{ if }x\in[-1,0)\\0&\text{ if }x=0\\x^2&\text{ if }x<-1\\x+1&\text{ if }x>0.\end{cases}\end{align}